# libcurl long poll with SSL and connection cache

Tags: c, nginx, libcurl

I am using libcurl with openssl for long poll on nginx.
To minimize the overhead we are using shared object to lock SSL and CONNECTION.

Backend is an nginx SSL with ticket timeout of 24h
Keepalive 7200s

We created a POC where our backend server responds every 0-15 seconds a state of server.

So what is my problem? We left this overnight and saw that connections to nginx from libcurl were being dropped and libcurl subsequently reconnects a new connection. What is strange is that this happens almost exactly every 32minutes.

This is part of the verbose log:

```
START:
10.10.2020 21:46:55,222 [DEBUG] - CURL - == Info:   Trying xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxx...  
10.10.2020 21:46:55,242 [DEBUG] - CURL - == Info: TCP_NODELAY set  
10.10.2020 21:46:55,343 [DEBUG] - CURL - == Info: Connected to xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxx (xx.xx.xx.xxx) port xxx (#0) 
10.10.2020 21:46:55,1181 [DEBUG] - CURL - => Send SSL data 
...<some other ssl and data exchange> ...
10.10.2020 21:46:55,4370 [DEBUG] - CURL - == Info: Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
10.10.2020 21:46:55,4400 [DEBUG] - CURL - <= Recv data
10.10.2020 21:46:55,4437 [DEBUG] - CURL - <= Recv SSL data 
10.10.2020 21:46:55,4463 [DEBUG] - CURL - <= Recv data 
10.10.2020 21:46:55,4491 [DEBUG] - CURL - == Info: Connection #0 to host xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxx  left intact 
...<almost 32minutes before next new connection we get:>...
10.10.2020 22:18:34,308 [DEBUG] - CURL - == Info: Found bundle for host  xx.xx.xx.xxx: 0x2b1710 [serially]  
10.10.2020 22:18:34,329 [DEBUG] - CURL - == Info: Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host  xx.xx.xx.xx
10.10.2020 22:18:34,354 [DEBUG] - CURL - == Info: Connected to xx.xx.xx.xx) ( xx.xx.xx.xx) port xxx (#0) 
10.10.2020 22:18:34,389 [DEBUG] - CURL - => Send SSL data 
10.10.2020 22:18:34,438 [DEBUG] - CURL - => Send header
10.10.2020 22:18:34,457 [DEBUG] - CURL - => Send data 
10.10.2020 22:18:34,480 [DEBUG] - CURL - == Info: upload completely sent off: 243 out of 243 bytes  
10.10.2020 22:18:49,579 [DEBUG] - CURL - <= Recv SSL data 
10.10.2020 22:18:49,596 [DEBUG] - CURL - == Info: Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse  
10.10.2020 22:18:49,612 [DEBUG] - CURL - <= Recv data
10.10.2020 22:18:49,628 [DEBUG] - CURL - <= Recv SSL data 
10.10.2020 22:18:49,639 [DEBUG] - CURL - <= Recv data
10.10.2020 22:18:49,680 [DEBUG] - CURL - == Info: Closing connection 0 
10.10.2020 22:18:49,701 [DEBUG] - CURL - => Send SSL data
10.10.2020 22:18:49,728 [DEBUG] - CURL - == Info: TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, close notify (256):  
10.10.2020 22:18:49,748 [DEBUG] - CURL - => Send SSL data 
...<new connection>...
10.10.2020 22:18:49,943 [DEBUG] - CURL - == Info:    Trying xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxx...  
10.10.2020 22:18:49,968 [DEBUG] - CURL - == Info: TCP_NODELAY set  
10.10.2020 22:18:49,1062 [DEBUG] - CURL - == Info: Connected to  xx.xx.xx.xx ( xx.xx.xx.xx) port xxx (#1)
```

Now as i can see that normaly the connection would be left intact, here in the disconnection i can see some other SSL exchanges. Would this mean that the nginx is droping the connection. Why 32 minutes ? From what would this timeout come ?

oh and the reponse is correctly received tnad then connection closed meaning that backend server (via nginx proxy) responded ok and the connection was closed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry found the problem!

keepalive_requests on nginx was set to 128 = 32 minutes of my requests :)

Thank you guys!